# Which one better approach - iterating x no of record OR 1 dml?

Tags: apex

My scenario is I want to create some record of any salesforce object. This object has self relationship. I will create one parent and x no of child record on the basis of some condition. The condition is if there is no child record generated on the basis of condition than parent record also should not created.

Following ways to implement this requirement, My doubt/Query is which one better approach:

First Way:

```
object__c obj = new object__c();
---statements------;
insert obj;

List<object__c> objs = new List<object__c>();
for(---x condition---){
     object__c tempObj = new object__c();     
     tempObj.self_lookup_field__c = obj.id;
     objs.add(tempObj);
}

if(objs.size() == 0)
    delete obj;
else
    insert objs;
```

Second Way:

```
object__c obj = new object__c();
---statements------;

List<object__c> objs = new List<object__c>();
for(---x condition---){
     object__c tempObj = new object__c();          
     objs.add(tempObj);
}

if(objs.size() > 0){
    insert obj;
    for(object__c rec : objs){
        rec.self_lookup_field__c = obj.id;
    }
    insert objs;
}
```

In first way: minimum dml 2, x items iteration 1 time.
In Second way: minimum dml 0, x items iteration 2 times.

Comment: Iterating would be better option instead of DML's because multiple DML may cause more back-end process like Trigger invocation or Workflow or any other process. It totally depends on the process flow.

Comment: @RCS Agree with you. But if there is no related Trigger and related workflow etc than?

Comment: It depends on how many iterations are to be done in both the loop. And it depends on the business use case that you want 1 parent or multiple. If you are trying to do this in test class then i would suggest you should try both the scenarios.

Comment: I'd use the second pattern. As well as looping (unless the number of items looped over is very large) being way cheaper than database calls, inserting and then deleting isn't elegant and as more logic is added in the future might have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @KeithC This is what I wanted to know, that programming operations are cheaper or not than database calls. Thnaks KeithC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself which of these two options is quicker:

1. Getting in your car, driving to the supermarket, buying a product, and then returning home. Or..
2. Opening the fridge door, confirming that you already have said product.

Assuming you don't live really close to the supermarket, you could repeat option 2 many many times before option 1 is complete.

It's a bit of a crude analogy, but it serves the point. DML operations are much shower than basic for loops that only rely on information that is already at hand.

Also, consider your two examples. In both cases you will always be performing the `for(---x condition---)` loop. So the only difference will be an extra loop to assign the `self_lookup_field__c` field.

The only other consideration I'd make is how often you expect the conditions to be true or false. If in the vast majority of the cases the looped conditions will be true then it might make more sense to insert the parent record first. This would slightly improve the performance for what most users will be doing.